How to define fixed-length arrays and dynamic arrays in SOME/IP using CommonAPI
I am working with CommonAPI and need to define an interface for a SOME/IP service. Specifically, I want to include both fixed-length arrays and dynamic arrays in the method parameters.
I’m using França IDL to define the interface, but I’m unsure of the correct syntax and best practices for defining both fixed-length and dynamic arrays. Could someone provide an example of how to define these arrays in a CommonAPI interface for SOME/IP?
I've reviewed some basic CommonAPI and França IDL documentation but couldn't find a clear example that fits this use case.
Example of what I think it might look like:
fidl


interface SomeIPExampleInterface {



    getStaticArray(out UInt32[4] staticArray) -> (Boolean success);



    setDynamicArray(in UInt32<10> dynamicArray) -> (Boolean success);



    getBothArrays(out UInt32[4] staticArray, out UInt32<10> dynamicArray) -> (Boolean success);



}

Is this the correct approach? Are there any specific considerations I need to be aware of when working with arrays in CommonAPI and SOME/IP?
